# Unable to clone rows of table using jquery

Tags: jquery, gsp

Here is my table in div:

```
<div class="employmentHistory">
        <table class="employmentHistoryForm">
            <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
            <tr class = "row">
                <td>
                    <g:textField id="name" name="company" class="company"></g:textField></td>
                <td>
                    <g:textField id="position" name="position" class="pos" ></g:textField></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="deleteThisRow"  value="Delete"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <g:textField name="sumCompany" id="destination" ></g:textField>
    </div>
```

Here is my jQuery script to clone the second row of the above table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //This line clones the row inside the '.row' class and transforms it to plain html.
            //var clonedRow = $('.row').clone().html();
            var clonedRow=$('.row').clone().html().find("input").each(function() {
                $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + index });
            }).end();

            //This line wraps the clonedRow and wraps it <tr> tags since cloning ignores those tags
            var appendRow = '<tr class = "row">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';

            $('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
                //this line get's the last row and appends the appendRow when it finds the correct row.
                $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:nth-child(2)').after(appendRow);
            });

            //when you click on the button called "delete", the function inside will be triggered.
            $('.deleteThisRow').live('click',function(){
                var rowLength = $('.row').length;
                //this line makes sure that we don't ever run out of rows.
                if(rowLength > 1){
                    deleteRow(this);
                }else{
                    $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
                    deleteRow(this);
                }
            });

            function deleteRow(currentNode){
                $(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
            }
            index++;
        });
```

When using the line in above script as:

```
var clonedRow = $('.row').clone().html();
```

The code perfectly clones the table row and appends it to the end of the table.But it duplicates the id fields of the textfields and I want to assign unique ids to the cloned rows which I try as:

```
var clonedRow=$('.row').clone().html().find("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + index });
                }).end();
```

But now the query does not work at all.So where am I mistaking and whats the solution?

Comment: If you want to clone elements with unique ids, then those elements really aren't unique, and thus shouldn't have unique ids. Why not just give them classes?

Comment: @BradM  Ok even giving classes would do but the classes must be unique in each row for the textfields.How should I make that happen with minimal changes in above code?

Comment: I don't know your logic/reasoning behind this, but I think you're over-analyzing this. The only thing that needs to be unique are rows (which technically already are if you base on index), but you can give rows a data-* attribute for more precise uniqueness. No matter what textbox/button is clicked inside a row, always traverse up the dom to the unique row and read it's index/data-*. Once you know the unique row where the event happened, you can base your logic on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar to this where I had a hidden section that had the mark-up I wanted to clone.  I'd set the id via javascript after it was cloned.

```
<div id="sectionToClone">
    <input class="company" type="text" />
    <input class="pos" type="text" />
    <!-- More stuff here -->
</div>
```

Then in my JavaScript I'd do something like this:

```
var clonedSection = $("#sectionToClone").clone();
var newMarkup = clonedSection.attr("id","section" + idCounter);
newMarkup.find(".company").attr("id","company" + idCounter);
newMarkup.find(".pos").attr("id","pos" + idCounter);
idCounter++;
$("#sectionToAppendTo").append(newMarkup);
```

Then each section would have unique id's when the replace happened.  When it came time to get all of the values, I would start a separate counter at 0 and increment to `idCounter` to pull the values out into an array of length `idCounter` and do with them as I needed.  Each look-up would look something like `$("#sectionX .company").val()`, `$("#sectionX .pos)`, etc...

In your CSS, make the section to clone hidden, by using an ID selector:

```
#sectionToClone{
    display: none;
}
```

Then when you change the ID in your JavaScript, the cloned section becomes visible since the CSS rule doesn't apply to it.

Comment: It worked well for what I was doing.  If each section has a unique ID, you won't need it on every element since you can make your selector specific enough to only find the one input. The code may require a bit of tweaking since I did most of it from memory.

Comment: A quick edit I made to the code: remove the .html() from the clone in my example, otherwise you'll have an HTML string and the .attr method will throw an error.

Comment: clonedSection.attr("id","section" + idCounter); would cause same id to be assigned to the elements inside a <tr> and would not work in my case as in my <tr> there are multiple input fields.

Comment: If you assigned it to the TR like: `<tr id="row1">` and each input had a different class, you could access it like `$("#row1 .company")`, `$("#row1 .pos")` then the next row would be `$("row2 .company")`, `$("row2 .pos")` and so on.  I admit that I am not familiar with gsp so if it requires unique ids per input, then I can see how it is a problem.  You could use the above selectors to get each element after the clone and set it's id that way. So clone, set the id, then use `newMarkup.find(".company").attr("id","company" + idCounter);` to set the id of the input within each cloned section.

Comment: I have finally solved the issue.I used a code similar to yours and assigned a unique class name to each input element inside a <tr>. So that if i need to access an input element, i can access it using its name attribute which is repeated across columns,and its class attribute which is repeated across rows. thanx!!

Comment: Good to hear.  I added an example of how I think you could set the ID's while cloning, in case you need to as well using the `find` method on the cloned section.